# Mongoose didn't automatic inscrease __v

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I don't know why mongoose didn't auto increase __v each time I call .save() method

I tried enable debug mode of mongoose and log the record before and after save line. But __v is not changed. I see also mongoose call `devices.updateOne()` without $inc operator.

Example:

```
const device = await device({ _id: '5fb3855c241cef097083803d' });

device.name = 'New Name';
device.updatedAt = new Date();

// try to log __v before update
console.log(device.__v); // --> 1
const result = await device.save();
// try to log __v after update
console.log(result.__v); // --> 1
```

Here is log in terminal

```
1
Mongoose: devices.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5fb3855c241cef097083803d") }, { '$set': { name: 'New Name', updatedAt: new Date("Wed, 06 Oct 2021 06:38:34 GMT") }}, { session: null })
1
```

MongoDb version: 5.0.2
Mongoose version: ^5.9.20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. Mongoose's default versioning scheme only checks the document's version if you modify an array in a potentially incompatible way. So I update only name, a string field so __v is not change because it never throw a VersionError if you do not modify any arrays.

set `optimisticConcurrency: true` if you want to increase __v even have change a String field